# How to get value of a domain constraint in Grails?

Tags: grails, constraints, grails-constraints

I have a text field whose length I would like to limit at the maxSize constraint of one of my domain classes.

So if I have a class foo:

```
class Foo {
    String bar

    static constraints = {
        bar(maxSize: 100)
    }
}
```

I would like to get that value of 100 for the property bar.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
def maxBarSize = Foo.constraints.bar.getAppliedConstraint( 'maxSize' ).maxSize
```

Comment: Checkout "Programmatic access" section in https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Constraints/Usage.html for modern Grails > 3

Answer (score 9):

I was having this issue in grails 3.1.8 and it has change a bit. at least in the gsp views I had to put this:

```
Foo.constrainedProperties ['bar']['maxSize']
```

Hope this help! Cheers!

Comment: Checkout "Programmatic access" section in https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Constraints/Usage.html

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code:

```
def foo = new Foo(bar: "stuff")
println foo.constraints.bar.maxSize
```